# Bootstrap V5 Alert Dismissing: Asking for confirmation when "Close Button" is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to add a nice confirmation message using Sweetalert2 to the bootstrap version 5 alert component.

**how does it work?**

when I clicked to "Close Button" (X) it should display a confirmation message with two options (Yes) and (No) if I clicked to (Yes) the alert component should be closed if (No) the alert component should be displayed.

that's it.

the issue that I face is in the close event when I put this code inside it and clicked to (Yes) Option in sweatalert2 confirmation message it shows me an error message in my dev console!

**reference:** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/alerts/#dismissing

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

**JS code:**

```
if ($(".alert").length) {
    $(".alert").on("close.bs.alert", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
            customClass: {
                confirmButton: "btn btn-primary",
                cancelButton: "btn btn-danger me-3",
            },
            buttonsStyling: false,
        });
        swalWithBootstrapButtons
            .fire({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                icon: "warning",
                confirmButtonText: "<i class='fas fa-check-circle me-1'></i> Yes, I am!",
                cancelButtonText: "<i class='fas fa-times-circle me-1'></i> No, I'm Not",
                showCancelButton: true,
                reverseButtons: true,
                focusConfirm: false,
            })
            .then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    var alertNode = document.querySelector(".alert");
                    var alert = bootstrap.Alert.getInstance(alertNode);
                    alert.close();
                }
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issues**

1. `alert` instance was not [created](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/alerts/#methods). so create it before closing the alert.
2. off the `close.bs.alert` event before closing the alert programmatically. It prevents infinite execution.

**Note**

You can also use jQuery with bootstrap 5. So it can also be simplified as

```
$(e.target).off('close.bs.alert').alert('close');
```

```js
$(".alert").on("close.bs.alert", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
    customClass: {
      confirmButton: "btn btn-primary",
      cancelButton: "btn btn-danger me-3",
    },
    buttonsStyling: false,
  });
  swalWithBootstrapButtons
    .fire({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
      icon: "warning",
      confirmButtonText: "<i class='fas fa-check-circle me-1'></i> Yes, I am!",
      cancelButtonText: "<i class='fas fa-times-circle me-1'></i> No, I'm Not",
      showCancelButton: true,
      reverseButtons: true,
      focusConfirm: false,
    })
    .then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        // using js
        var alertNode = document.querySelector(".alert");
        var alert = new bootstrap.Alert(alertNode);
        
        $(alertNode).off('close.bs.alert')
        alert.close();

        // using jQuery
        // $(e.target).off('close.bs.alert').alert('close'); 
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>


<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show mt-5" role="alert">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```